# Is it possible to query oracle with tuples in dapper?

Tags: .net, oracle, dapper

In oracle you can query with tuples:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3 from MyTable where (Col1, Col2) in ((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

Now, if I use Dapper, what should I pass in parameter for my tuple ?

I tried that but it does not work:

```
var objs = conn.Query("select Col1, Col2, Col3 from MyTable where (Col1, Col2) in :arg", 
              new { arg = new List<Tuple<int, int>>()
                              {
                                Tuple.Create(1, 2), Tuple.Create(3, 4)
                              } }, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

To use tuples in a query like this the resulting syntax needs to be correct, so for Oracle the resultant parsed query string needs to wind up looking like:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3 from MyTable where (Col1, Col2) in ( (1,2),(3,4) );
```

To be honest, I've never tried that using variable replacement, and I am unfamiliar with Dapper, but at least this points you to your desired output. Does Dapper put the enclosing brackets around the output list for example?

Comment: I've downvoted your answer since your are not answering the question at all.
FYI, when you do "select * from T where id in :e", dapper correctly use parameter binding and so oracle is happy.
Doing what you suggest "select * from T where id in (:e)" will result in oracle considering you are using tuple syntax which would be wrong